# DrawToBitmap is not working on windows xp but in windows 7 is

Tags: drawtobitmap

I have hosted a custom control in datagridview, let's me say CustomControl (third party control), and cell is painting only when entering in edit mode. If exit edit mode, it is not visible so I have overrided the paint method (see below). It is working ok in windows 7 but not in windows xp. DrawToBitmap is failing. Any ideas?

```
        protected override void Paint(
        Graphics graphics,
        Rectangle clipBounds,
        Rectangle cellBounds,
        int rowIndex,
        DataGridViewElementStates cellState,
        object value,
        object formattedValue,
        string errorText,
        DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
        DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
        DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)         {             // Call the base class method to paint the default​ cell appearance.
        base.Paint(
            graphics,
            clipBounds,
            cellBounds,
            rowIndex,
            cellState,
            value,
            formattedValue,
            errorText,
            cellStyle,
            advancedBorderStyle,
            paintParts);

        CustomControl customControl= (CustomControl)this.DataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[this.ColumnIndex].Value;

        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(cellBounds.Width, cellBounds.Height);

        // Resize propertyEditor control to cell bounds
        propertyEditor.Height = cellBounds.Hei​ght;
        propertyEditor.Width = cellBounds.Widt​h;

        // Sets the cell's backcolor according to the data​ grid view's color
        customControl.BackColor = this.DataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[this.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor;

        // Finally paint the propertyEditor control       ​     
        customControl.DrawToBitmap(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, customControl.Width, customControl.Height​));
        graphics.DrawImage(img, cellBounds.Loc​ation);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce a really similar issue with Windows 7 by removing the row `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` from my `Program.cs`.
I was using a simple ComboBox not something third party but the effect was the same. To overcome the issue I had to do three things:

1. Set the (custom)control to visible true so that `DrawToBitmap` will surely be able to render it
2. Set the control's parent to the `DataGridView` (e.g. `customControl.Parent = DataGridView`) so that it has a parent that's also visible
3. Move the control out of the visible area (e.g. `customControl.Location = new Point(0, -(customControl.Height))` so the control isn't showing up where it shouldn't

This worked in my case but it may depend on how your custom control handles the `DrawToBitmap` function.

I'm curious if this will help in your case or if anyone can find a more elegant solution.